# Access Iframe Document Element Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

- Hi, I was working on the Iframe and then I stuck on a problem.
- I want to access the `Iframe's` elements, but I can't.
- I use the `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("element")` to access.
- Here is my code

- On `10.html` file

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Onboard Access Iframe Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./10.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="layer">
      <div class="iframe-container">

        <!-- I wanted to access the element inside the iframe bellow  -->
        <iframe
          class="iframe-element"
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          src="./iframe.html"
          frameborder="0"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./10.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- On `iframe.html` file

  ```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML For Iframe</title>

    <style>
      body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .element {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>   </head>   <body>
    <div class="element element1">1</div>
    <div class="element element2">2</div>
    <div class="element element3">3</div>
    <div class="element element4">4</div>
    <div class="element element5">5</div> 
    </body> 
    </html>
  ```
- On `10.js` file

  ```
  (function () {
  const classes = {
    iframeElement: "iframe-element",
  };

  /**
   *
   * @param {HTMLIFrameElement} iframe
   */
  function getIframeElements(iframe) {
    console.log(
      iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("element")
    );
  }

  function main() {
    const iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
      classes.iframeElement
    )[0];

    getIframeElements(iframeElement);
  }

  main();
  })();
  ```
- On `10.css` file

  ```
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }

  .iframe-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  }
  ```

- From an `HTML`, Is there any way to access the Iframe's Elements?
- Thank you guys very much!

Comment: "_I can't_" doesn't describe the problem well, what is the exact error message?

Comment: @Teemu, hm... I want to access the Iframe's Element.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know you "_can't_" access those elements in the iframe?

Comment: @Teemu, Because I tested something, the `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Comment: This is like milking a cow ... What was the exact result of the test?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for iframe to load before you can access it's dom. Call `getIframeElements` inside load event of iframe.

Something like this

```
 iframeElement.addEventListener("load", () =>
      getIframeElements(iframeElement)
 );
```